# How to get id of inserted item from websql db using coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, cordova, coffeescript, web-sql

I am trying to write a coffeescript websql function to insert some test data. I want to be able to get the id of inserted item because I am generating ids automatically while saving the item. I have tried to do it like here,

```
 insert: (data) ->
        console.log "Inserting test data.."
        @db.transaction (tx) =>
            tx.executeSql(@INSERT_QUERY,
                data,
                (tx,@results) => console.log(@results.insertId),
                (tx,error) => console.error(error),
            )
        @results
```

But the id variable always comes out of as 'undefined' because return value, @results, above is 'undefined'. Not sure why that's happening though.

```
id = root.taskTable.insert(data)
```

I am also attaching the output java script code from that coffeescript code above, just in case.

```
dbTable.prototype.insert = function(data) {
      console.log("Inserting test data");
      this.db.transaction((function(_this) {
        return function(tx) {
          return tx.executeSql(_this.INSERT_QUERY, data, function(tx, results) {
            _this.results = results;
            return console.log(_this.results.insertId);
          }, function(tx, error) {
            return console.error(error);
          });
        };
      })(this));
      return this.results;
    };
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(_this.results);`? That would allow you to traverse the entire results object and possibly find the object containing the id.

Comment: OK, but if I just do console.log(_this.results) how exactly I would be able to traverse it? Sorry if this is something obvious. Google didn't help me interpret it any better.

Comment: You will need to hook up to a remote inspector. What device or emulator are you testing with and what OS are you on?

Comment: I am testing this on phonegap with ripple emulator. I can see the console log in chrome. But I want that id to be accessible in code for further processing.

Comment: When you see the results in the console you should be able to click into the object and see the properties in it. this will show you where the id is (if it's in there). If it is then you can change your code to grab the id. if it's not in there you will need look up how to access the id (might be a method you need to call)